# Edit discord.Interactions Response

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to update my old Discord bot to use the new app_commands. After converting test = await message.channel.reply("string") to test = await interaction.response.send_message("string"), I can't use test.edit(content = "new string").

tested code:

```
@tree.command(name = "test")
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    test = await interaction.response.send_message(f"string")
    time.sleep(1)
    await test.edit(content = "new string")
```

I expected the interaction response to edit to "new string" instead of putting out an error. How is this done with the new app_commands component?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use time.sleep() because it blocks the event loop and prevents your bot from processing other events, including message edits.

```
import discord
import asyncio

@tree.command(name="test")
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    test = await interaction.response.send_message("string")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Use asyncio.sleep to introduce a delay
    await test.edit(content="new string")
```

By replacing time.sleep(1) with "await asyncio.sleep(1)", you allow the event loop to continue processing other events while waiting for the delay to finish.